# Show tick label outisde of plot area in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis

I am using `ggplot` to create a multiple panel graph with area filled values. I want to cut off the graph exactly at the maximum x value (year) and still label that year. When I specify the exact values, it doesn't print the final value (result when values 2001, 2005 and 2010 are set by `breaks` is shown on left). I also want to specify which tick values are set (default doesn't make sense, see print out on right as example) and I have set the axis tick labels to include the last value on the x-axis but it does not print fully (it is cut off at the edge of the plot region). How can I get ggplot to show the last value as I set it by breaks? Code below for dummy example shown here.

EDIT: corrected breaks to 2001, 2005, 2010 in code (not 2100).

[image]

```
set<-data.frame(year=c(2001:2010), values=c(1:10))
g1<-ggplot(set, aes(x=year,y=values))+
      geom_area(data=set)+
      theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
            panel.background = element_blank(), 
            axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))+
      scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0, 0), breaks=c(2001, 2005, 2010)) + #label at 25-year intervals
      scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0))


g2<-ggplot(set, aes(x=year,y=values))+
  geom_area(data=set)+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), 
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))+
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0, 0)) + #label at 25-year intervals
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0))

ggarrange(g1, g2, nrow=1, ncol=2)
```

Comment: have you tried adding `limits = c(2001,2010)` to scale_x_continuous? Also, you have the breaks at 2001, 2005 and 2100 - that on purpose?

Comment: @Tjebo adding `limits = c(2001, 2010)` gives the same result (can't see the last value). Yes, I want to set the exact tick labels that include the first and last value and an intermediate value.

Comment: What I meant, have you tried 2010 instead of 2100

Comment: Yeah, you're going to hate seeing that you've made a typo in your `breaks=` argument.  :/  You have 2100 instead of 2010.  It works fine then although you get some of the "2010" label cut off as a result of plot margin clipping.  If you get clipping like that, you can add `theme(plot.margin = margin(10,15,10,10, "points")` to add some padding (worked for me).

Comment: @Tjebo Well, that's a silly typo. I will fix the initial question to make it 2010! My actual dataset goes from 2001 to 2100 but I had simplified it for the example here. I had tried changing `margin` and `cm` but my axis was still not there so I don't quite understand what happened but it worked with your suggested values.

Comment: @Tjebo Your tip worked so if you post as an answer, I'll accept it gladly:)

Comment: I just pointed towards the typo - the margin tip is @chemdork123 's merit!

Comment: oops. I read too quickly and I didn't notice that there was a second user helping me out. Sorry to @chemdork123. I have accepted your answer, although the problem itself wasn't the typo since my initial dataset was different.

Comment: Hey no problem.  It's a shared answer here.  Just glad we could help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@Tjebo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7941188/tjebo)'s suggestion as well... the inherent problem lies in your `breaks` argument containing a typo :).  Should work fine using `2010` instead of `2100`. Whoops!

However, the use of `expand=c(0,0)` tends to result in cutting off the axis tick labels as a result of the label clipping out of bounds.  The fix for that?  Just extend the "bounds".  Here, you should use `theme(plot.margin=...` to push the margins out a bit.  [Some information can be found here to guide you](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/element.html), but really just play around with the margins, noting that the format is generally `theme(plot.margin = margin(t, r, b, l, unit))`

Where: t, r, b, and l represent "top", "right", "bottom", and "left", respectively, and unit can be a few things (here I suggested "points").  With that being said, I found that this worked for your example case for the plot on the left:

```
theme(plot.margin = margin(10,15,10,10, "points")
```